# Is there a way to make Android print a stacktrace on skipped frames

Tags: android

My Android app receives regular warnings about skipping frames. I'm not sure where it could possibly come from. Is there a way to make Android add a stacktrace of the UI thread? Based on that it would be easy to figure out the code that's calling frames to be skipped.

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that. And it's not possible technically.
In order to provide a smoothness reacting on user events android application renders its UI with *60 frames per second* rate. What it means, that every *16 ms* main (UI) thread is used to render your apps UI. When something is blocking UI thread from doing that - you're starting to see such messages (`Skipped 51 frames!`) in a `Logcat`. By saying *blocking UI thread* I mean that someone (your apps components) are using it too much.

In a weird comparison you can imagine UI thread as a public toilet. Every one is using it (your activity, fragment, views, etc.). The `Choreographer` *must* use it every 16 ms. So every 16 ms it tries to open a toilet door and render UI for you :) When it is closed, it waits (and counts) untils someone frees it, and screams out into `Logcat` that someone wasted his time to render `n` frames. So there's no way he will also print a stack trace (like you want), cause he's waiting and doesn't know who is blocking the toilet...

While understanding it is pretty simple, to figure out what's the real reason of blocking main thread is not that simple. But #1 cause is to do much work on an UI thread. To figure out who is responsible for that, you can check your code by your own and define (and measure) any place that potentially could block UI. The most obvious examples are database access, network requests, image processing, etc. To help you with that you can use `CPU Profiler`. To find out more, please follow the links below.

https://vaibhavtolia.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/79/

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler

Comment: "No, there is no way to do that. And it's not possible technically." It's very possible technically. Looking at the Android source code, it looks like the Android team is not doing it. There could be a flag that a developer sets. (That way, it doesn't slow anything down for real users. If the flag is set and the Choreographer detects skipped frames, it could trigger the JVM to do a thread dump. It could even be smarter by getting the UI thread and simply writing the stacktrace out.

Comment: What flag are you talking about? I didn't found any trace printing code in the Choreographer.

Comment: There isn't, but Android developers could have created such a thing. It's not technically impossible to do (for them).

Comment: Try to make your own `Choreographer`, which will not draw the frames, but will schedule a check for every 16ms, and this chech will be delayed much, will print a stack trace.